# inline-block element doesn't adapt to image with width:auto

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a div the same width as the containing image with height:100% and width:auto.

With display:inline-block it seems to work but only if you don't resize the browser. The div `slide` always keep the initial width. How can I change this behavior?

This is my code:

CSS:

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery{
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
}
.slide{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/1">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

or here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ykzokoxd/

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
.element{
 -webkit-animation: ibfix infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ibfix { 
 from {max-width:100%;padding:0;} 
 to {max-width:99.9%;padding:0.01%} 
}
```

**Edit:** "Repainting/refreshing inline-block element, so width is adapting to child img"

https://jsfiddle.net/ykzokoxd/2/

Comment: Your contribution would have more value if you were to include some explanation about how it fixes the problem.